# How to access the class member functions from a weak pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I am a complete newbie to smart pointers, and I have never dealt with `weak_ptr` in C++.

I have a function in class `Y`, that takes in as parameter a `weak_ptr` of class `X`.

Inside the function in class `Y`, I need to access the member functions of class `X` through the `weak_ptr`.

For reference, here is a rough class definition:

Y.cpp

```cpp
class Y {
  public : Y();
           ~Y();
           int foo(std::weak_ptr<X> x);
};
```

X.cpp

```cpp
class X {
 public : std::string func1();
          int func2();
};
```

Inside of the `foo()` function in class `Y`, I need to be able to access the functions `func1` and `func2` using the `weak_ptr x`.

I don't know why I need to use `weak_ptr`, but that's what I am supposed to implement.

I am unable to find any beginner-friendly sample code using `weak_ptr`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock ?

Comment: Tip: I've almost never needed a `shared_ptr`. You probably don't either.

Comment: I am not sure why but I have been asked to specifically use a weak_ptr in my case. Would love to know in which scenarios weak_ptr is used, and when they are helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert it to a `shared_ptr` first, using `.lock()`:

```
int foo(std::weak_ptr<X> x)
{
    std::shared_ptr<X> y = x.lock(); // Or `auto y = x.lock();`.
    y->do_stuff();
}
```

The rationale is that a `weak_ptr` doesn't hold ownership (unlike `shared_ptr`), so if you could dereference it directly, there would be a risk of the target object being destroyed from a different thread while you're doing that.

It's might be a good idea to check if the resulting pointer (`y`) is not null before using it, unless crashing if it's null is an acceptable way to handle an error in your case.

It's a **bad** idea to call `.lock()` every time (instead of once and saving the result to a variable), since the target can be destroyed between calls (and it would be more costly).